# Assign MouseHover event to newly created Control

Tags: c#, .net, controls

This is the new control add code part:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            var newLabel = new Label();
            newLabel.Location = new Point(x, y);
            newLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);

            newLabel.Name = "lbl" + realpocsed.ToString();

            if (value2== "Value2")
            {
                newLabel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseMove);
                newLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseDown);
            }
            if (value== "Value1")
            {
                newLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseHover);

            }

            panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
```

The `MouseHover` event look like this:

```
        private void MyControl_MouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip ToolTip1 = new ToolTip();
        ToolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        ToolTip1.Show("t", X); // X should be name of the newly created label
    }
```

May I ask if is there any way to assign the newly created with name `"lbl" + realpocsed.ToString()` instead of `X`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use anonymous delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `for`:

```
newLabel.MouseHover += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip ToolTip1 = new ToolTip();
    ToolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
    ToolTip1.Show("t", newLabel);
};
```

Update:

```
if (value == "Value1")
{
    newLabel.MouseHover += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolTip ToolTip1 = new ToolTip();
        ToolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        ToolTip1.Show("t", newLabel);
    };
}
```

Comment: You can not pass string as `Object` name. This is totally a wrong code suggestion

Comment: I don't follow. `realpocsed` is outer variable, not string. This code is inside `for`, where we have `realpocsed` object.

Comment: `"lbl"` is an string, concatenating with `realpocsed.ToString()` this is also an `string`. So the whole argument is actually an `string`. This will not even compile and will give you the **compile time error**.

Comment: The second parameter in the `ToolTip.Show(string text, IWin32Window window)` is not a string.  It should be the calling window control.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning a MouseDown event to your MouseHover code, not sure you want that.

It should look like this:

```
newLabel.MouseHover += MyControl_MouseHover;
```

For your X, you would have to cast the sender:

```
ToolTip1.Show("Hover Message Here", (Label)sender);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any object by creating its name in string. The simple way to do that is to pass the object reference:

```
ToolTip1.Show("t", (sender as Label));
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the second parameter should be an IWin32Window, not a string.